# Effect of increasing Extracellular Na+ Concentration on resting voltage and likelihood of an action potential of occuring

Tags: cell-membrane, membrane

If you increase the extracellular Na+ concentration how will this effect the resting voltage and likelihood that an action potential of will occur?

Please explain using the Goldman–Hodgkin–Katz voltage equation if you have that understanding.  I can typically understand mathematical functions and relationships.

My guess is that the membrane will become more hyperpolarized and the likelihood for an action potential will go down.  I have read some explain otherwise and I would like help confirming or denying my current understanding.